# DNS not fully propagated after more than 48 hours, MX records not even showing on online tools, Google Workspace not working

Tags: hosting, nameserver, mx-record, google

A few weeks ago I transferred my domain `equimobi.com` from Google Domains to Bluehost. 5 days ago I modified the nameservers to bluehost (ns1.Bluehost.com, ns2.Bluehost.com) and created the MX records that Google provides you to reactivate Google Workspace.

At first everything seemed to work well, Google recognized the MX records about 24 hours later.

The next day I clicked a button within bluehost to link my hosting package to the transferred domain and this is where I think everything started to fail.

My client reported to me the next day that the emails sent to him are bouncing with an error message "your message could not be delivered because the address could not be found or it cannot receive mail." And his Google Workspace interface show the message to set up the MX Records again.

It's been a long time and my domain hasn't propagated completely, and the MX Records don't seem to be found even though I do have them created on bluehost.

Bluehost support told me today that they were going to repush my DNS, but it's been more than 4 hours and the MX records still don't seem to be found.

What should I do to have the MX Records and Google Workspace working again?
Thanks!

Comment: Talk with your registrar and DNS provider. When you don't do that yourself there's not a whole lot you *can* do.

Comment: Agreed the zone is completely empty `equimobi.com.           3600    IN      HINFO    "RFC8482" ""
;; Received 62 bytes from 162.159.25.175#53(ns2.bluehost.com) in 4 ms`

Comment: Did you have DNSSEC enabled?

Comment: @AlexD I don't have DNSSEC enabled.

Comment: Yes @vidarlo i've been talking with them but they are not helping a lot, they just say that it's already 'propagating'

Comment: Did you have DNSSEC enabled before transferring the domain?

Comment: I'm not really sure about that @AlexD, the domain was bought originally in Google Domains. But im not sure if it had that setting enabled.

Answer (score 1):

> A few weeks ago I transferred my domain equimobi.com from Google
> Domains to Bluehost. 5 days ago I modified the nameservers to bluehost
> (ns1.Bluehost.com, ns2.Bluehost.com) and created the MX records that
> Google provides you to reactivate Google Workspace.
>
> At first everything seemed to work well, Google recognized the MX
> records about 24 hours later.

Ok, so it appears that at that point in time, the correct `MX` records were in place.

> The next day I clicked a button within bluehost to link my hosting
> package to the transferred domain and this is where I think everything
> started to fail.

It would fit your problem description if, for whatever reason, that button also changed the `MX` records. This may well be the case.

> My client reported to me the next day that the emails sent to him are
> bouncing with an error message "your message could not be delivered
> because the address could not be found or it cannot receive mail." And
> his Google Workspace interface show the message to set up the MX
> Records again.

Indeed, the desired `MX` records are *not* there on the Bluehost authoritative nameservers.

See a query directed straight at `ns1.bluehost.com` (fwiw `ns2` responds identically):

```
$ dig @ns1.bluehost.com equimobi.com MX +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.18.19-1~deb12u1-Debian <<>> @ns1.bluehost.com equimobi.com MX +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25397
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;equimobi.com.                  IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
equimobi.com.           14400   IN      MX      10 equimobi.com.
equimobi.com.           14400   IN      MX      0 mail.equimobi.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.equimobi.com.      14400   IN      A       50.87.253.11
equimobi.com.           14400   IN      A       50.87.253.11

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 162.159.24.80#53(ns1.bluehost.com) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 31 22:14:59 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110

$
```

There are `MX` records, but those have nothing to do with Google Workspace. Maybe some default template at Bluehost?

> It's been a long time and my domain hasn't propagated completely, and
> the MX Records don't seem to be found even though I do have them
> created on bluehost.

The whole "propagation" wording is a bit of a pet peeve, and I'll not go on too much about it, but I really think it's more helpful to think about it in the concrete terms of:

1. The process of publishing your new/changed records to the authoritative nameservers (usually fast, and then this is barely a factor)
2. Waiting for old cached data to expire from caches on resolver servers/clients (based on the TTL of the records that were served earlier, usually quite long)

My impression of your current situation is that things appear to be in a steady state of badness at this point.
For whatever reason bad `MX` records have been published, and if a fix has been attempted not even "step 1" above has happened.

Ie, as the current `MX` records being served by Bluehost are bad. Meaning that at least from a strict DNS perspective it's not a matter of waiting, because the published data on the authoritative end is not even what you want, so it's not about caching or anything like that.
The `MX` records on the Bluehost nameservers need to be fixed first and only after that, there is the matter of waiting for caches to expire.

> Bluehost support told me today that they were going to repush my DNS,
> but it's been more than 4 hours and the MX records still don't seem to
> be found.

It's not clear what exactly that means, but assuming that this "push" is somewhat near-instant in terms of getting the right data to the Bluehost nameservers themselves ("step 1" above), it doesn't appear to have fixed the `MX` records.

> What should I do to have the MX Records and Google Workspace working
> again?

If the problem is not fixable/visible from whatever admin UI you have access to at Bluehost, it sounds like you see the correct `MX` records in the admin UI, but those are apparently not on their nameservers, I think you pretty much have to get their help to fix the `MX` records (other than more drastic solutions like hosting DNS elsewhere, I suppose).

In addition to the Google Workspace `MX` records not being there at all, there is also another problem that will prevent the domain from working right in general.
The domain name is indicated as DNSSEC signed with a `DS` record in the delegation, but the zone at the Bluehost nameservers is not signed at all (and obviously then not with the specific key indicated in the `DS`). See https://dnsviz.net/d/equimobi.com/ZbrRsQ/dnssec/ for a more detailed view of this.
You will need to remove/update the `DS` through your domain registrar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, so as I understand, I have to keep talking with them so they fix it from their side. And yeah, i'm starting to think hosting elsewhere would be the best option right now. I will talk to support and post what they tell me later.